# Bloquear redirect de extensões e pastas com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Estou de todas as formas tentando criar um redirect com htaccess e consegui da seguinte forma:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:index\.php|robots\.txt)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://meusite.com/novapasta/$1 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

O problema que na hora que digito na URL qualquer outro arquivo que não seja index.php ou robots.txt ele joga para essa pasta.

Ex: sitemap.xml ele está direcionando meusite.com/novapasta/sitemap.xml e não quero isso.

Tentei colocar:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)$
```

Mas ele não aceita e direciona da raiz para pasta /novapasta/sitemap.xml

Até pastas ele está direcionando.

Ex: `meusite.com/imagens` para `meusite.com/novapasta/imagens/`

Como posso barrar isso?

O que eu preciso:

Então sempre testo em modo privado e ele ainda direciona. Na verdade tenho um site que ele tinha uma querystring que faz os links ficarem

- `http://meusite.com/produto.php?produto=$1`
- `http://meusite.com/produto`

Agora quero jogar tudo para essa nova pasta

- `http://meusite.com/novapasta/produto`

Só que com esse redirect se eu tento acessar:

`http://meusite.com/sitemap.xml`, `http://meusite.com/imagens/` e `http://meusite.com/diretorioqualquer`

ele joga para:

`http://meusite.com/novapasta/sitemap.xml`, `http://meusite.com/novapasta/imagens/` e
`http://meusite.com/novapasta/diretorioqualquer`

Os únicos que ele não joga são o index e o robots e gostaria de jogar apenas o que vem do `produto.php?produto=$1`

---

Então sempre testo em modo privado e ele ainda direciona.
Na verdade tenho um site que ele tinha uma querystring que faz os links ficarem

http://meusite.com/produto.php?produto=$1

http://meusite.com/produto

Agora quero jogar tudo para essa nova pasta

http://meusite.com/novapasta/produto

Só que com esse redirect se eu tento acessar

http://meusite.com/sitemap.xml

http://meusite.com/imagens/

http://meusite.com/diretorioqualquer

ele joga para

http://meusite.com/novapasta/sitemap.xml

http://meusite.com/novapasta/imagens/

http://meusite.com/novapasta/diretorioqualquer

Os únicos que ele não joga são o index e o robots e gostaria de jogar apenas o que vem do produto.php?produto=$1

Comment: Respondi brevemente, mas pelo que entendi parece que você está usando um `.htaccess` sem saber exatamente o que quer, quero dizer você quer uma coisa, mas o teu htaccess está fazendo uma coisa totalmente diferente do que você precisa. Diga-me você quer realmente bloquear todas urls e liberar apenas algumas? Por que se for isto, o teu htaccess está ok, mas se não então o teu htaccess não tem sentido para o teu projeto.

Comment: Na verdade não tenho muito conhecimento no .htaccess por isso estou quebrando a cabeça com vários testes

Comment: Diga-me você quer realmente bloquear todas urls e liberar apenas algumas?

Comment: Depende o servidor tem permissão configurar **htaccess**, e nada fácil configurar, se for locaweb é reclamar suporte, recomendo de usar **cPanel** é util de usar e vai ajudar, e o servidor IIS pode muito trampo. Pesquise sobre "URL amigável" pode ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Rafael quando o navegador recebe um 301 isto fica no cache, portanto isto funciona:

```apacheconf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:index\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)$
```

O problema é que para o navegador a página antiga não existe mais por que você usou a *flag* `R=301`.

Para resolver isto, limpe o cache e abra novamente o navegador ou abra o navegador em modo *Privado*.

Note que o seu `rewritecond` bloqueia qualquer url, exceto: index.php e robots.txt e sitemap.xml.

Você perguntou:

> Como posso barrar isso?

Eu não entendi bem o que você quer, se você não quer que nenhuma url seja bloqueada, então você vai ter que entender o que está a fazer, pois o seu código manda fazer isto exatamente. A solução pratica seria não usar o `.htaccess`.